# strange behavior of kafka tool : kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to get offset using timestamp, and try the kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell command tool. The document is: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools

I think this command return the latest N offsets before timestamp we specify. But I tried several command and get confused...

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
  --broker-list ka1:9092 \
  --time -1 \
  --topic test_topic \
  --offsets 100 \
  --partitions 61
```

which returns:

```
test_topic:61:6269917760,6257457002
```

then:

```
 kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
   --broker-list ka1:9092 \
   --time -2 \
   --topic test_topic \
   --offsets 100 \
   --partitions 61
```

which returns:

```
test_topic:61:6257457002
```

then:

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
   --broker-list ka1:9092 \
   --time 1430742921000 \
   --topic test_topic \
   --offsets 100 \
   --partitions 61
```

which returns empty set!!!

```
test_topic:61:
```

How does this tool work?

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue? I am getting same behaviour and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Maybe It is because the GetOffsetShell could not get the exact offset according to the insert timestamp. You could look inside the source code,  kafka store data into multiple blocks, it first found the block according to the timestamp , then return the first record in this block. so if your blocks are very large, for example, you only have one block, it will return the first record of this block....

Answer (score 2):

Kafka stores its log in "log segments". These are set in the config:

```
# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
```

kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell is matching timestamps of the log segments rather then the timestamp of the offset it self.

Therefore every log segment will have a size of 1073.74 megabytes (default). So if your messages in your history will have all together over 3,222 megabytes, you'll be able to query 4 different log segments by a timestamp.

Thats why for this:

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
  --broker-list ka1:9092 \
  --time 1430742921000 \
  --topic test_topic \
  --offsets 100 \
  --partitions 61
```

You got returned:

```
test_topic:61:
```

As you were querying timestamp which is, on a timeline, before any log segment, as tool is matching last modified date of the log segment to the timestamp provided.

I found this out by creating a test of measuring size of the log files and querying the timestamp after creation of every new log.